# Linear mapping and linear span

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

This is about a linear algebra problem.
We have $f\in L(\mathbb{R^3},\mathbb{R^2})$ such that :

- $f(1,0,0)=(0,1)$
- $f(1,1,0)=(1,0)$
- $f(1,1,1)=(1,1)$

We need to find $f(x,y,z)$.

My professor started with $(x,y,z)=\alpha(1,0,0)+\beta(1,1,0)+\gamma(1,1,1)$ but isn't this supposing that $f$ is mapping from $<F>$ not $\mathbb{R^3}$ (with $F=\{(1,0,0), (1,1,0), (1,1,1)\}$)?

Comment: You can show that those three vectors span $\mathbb{R}^3$. So $\langle F\rangle = \mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Find $f(0,1,0)$ and $f(0,0,1)$ by linearity of $f$.

Comment: Can you please explain? I have found them but nothing is jumping out except $f(0,0,1)=f(1,0,0)$.

Comment: Still use linearity for the $f$-image of $(x, y, z) =x(1,0,0)+y(0,1,0)+z(0,0,1)$.

Comment: Much thanks Berci!